Using jinja2schema with custom filters
Anyone know how to prevent invalid template errors with custom filter functions and jinja2schema.infer()?
This will throw an exception because my_filter is not a built-in:
from jinja2schema import infer
template='{{ something | my_filter }}'
print(infer(template))

Can I set an underlying jinja2.Environment().filters value somehow?

Nvm, turns out templates were just the tip of the iceberg in things NOT supported by jinja2schema.
